# Find out which object being added to NSMutableArray is nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, runtime-error

I started a project using ARC, and I'm inserting a few objects into an `NSMutableArray`. The objects have all started out as `NSString`s, and when attempting to add these objects into the array, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

This array is holding several objects. Is there a quick way for me to find which of the objects I'm attempting to put into the array is `nil`?

Comment: The debugger? Include some code and we'll take a look?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code?

Comment: `if(!object)` or `if(object == nil)` before you call `insertObject:atIndex:`

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable break on Objective-C exceptions
2. Run your code in the debugger, it will then stop and show you the exact line where the nil value is inserted

How to break on Objective-C exceptions? Well it depends on your version of Xcode:

1. Xcode 3: Run menu -> Stop on Objective-C Exceptions
2. Xcode 4: in the breakpoints view (Cmd-6), hit the + button and Add Exception Breakpoint…, then set the type to Objective-C and hit Done

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you that much without seeing the code, but you could put `NSLog()` statements where you insert objects into the NSMutableArray and then look at the last message printed. The place where you put the `NSLog()` with the last message is where the error should be.

Hope this helps!